# Recursive x3 parser with results passing around

Tags: c++, recursion, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

(1) Say we want to parse a simple recursive block surrounded by `{}`.

```
{
    Some text.
    {
        {
            Some more text.
        }
        Some Text again.
        {}
    }
}
```

This recursive parser is quite simple.

```
x3::rule<struct idBlock1> const ruleBlock1{"Block1"};
auto const ruleBlock1_def =
    x3::lit('{') >>
    *(
        ruleBlock1 |
        (x3::char_ - x3::lit('}'))
    ) >>
    x3::lit('}');

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(ruleBlock1)
```

(2) Then the block becomes more complex. It could also be surrounded by `[]`.

```
{
    Some text.
    [
        {
            Some more text.
        }
        Some Text again.
        []
    ]
}
```

We need somewhere to store what kind of opening bracket that we have. Since x3 does not have locals, we may use attribute (`x3::_val`) instead.

```
x3::rule<struct idBlock2, char> const ruleBlock2{"Block2"};
auto const ruleBlock2_def = x3::rule<struct _, char>{} =
    (
        x3::lit('{')[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)='}';})] |
        x3::lit('[')[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)=']';})]
    ) >>
    *(
        ruleBlock2 |
        (
            x3::char_ - 
            (
                x3::eps[([](auto& ctx){x3::_pass(ctx)='}'==x3::_val(ctx);})] >> x3::lit('}') |
                x3::eps[([](auto& ctx){x3::_pass(ctx)=']'==x3::_val(ctx);})] >> x3::lit(']')
            )
        )
    ) >>
    (
        x3::eps[([](auto& ctx){x3::_pass(ctx)='}'==x3::_val(ctx);})] >> x3::lit('}') |
        x3::eps[([](auto& ctx){x3::_pass(ctx)=']'==x3::_val(ctx);})] >> x3::lit(']')
    );

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(ruleBlock2)
```

(3) The block content (surrounded part), we call it argument, may be much more complicated than this example. So we decide to create a rule for it. This attribute solution is not working in this case. Luckily we still have `x3::with` directive. We can save the open bracket (or expecting close bracket) in a stack reference and pass it to the next level.

```
struct SBlockEndTag {};
x3::rule<struct idBlockEnd> const ruleBlockEnd{"BlockEnd"};
x3::rule<struct idArg> const ruleArg{"Arg"};
x3::rule<struct idBlock3> const ruleBlock3{"Block3"};
auto const ruleBlockEnd_def =
    x3::eps[([](auto& ctx){
        assert(!x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().empty());
        x3::_pass(ctx)='}'==x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().top();
    })] >> 
    x3::lit('}') 
    |
    x3::eps[([](auto& ctx){
        assert(!x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().empty());
        x3::_pass(ctx)=']'==x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().top();
    })] >>
    x3::lit(']');
auto const ruleArg_def =
    *(
        ruleBlock3 |
        (x3::char_ - ruleBlockEnd)
    );
auto const ruleBlock3_def =
    (
        x3::lit('{')[([](auto& ctx){x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().push('}');})] |
        x3::lit('[')[([](auto& ctx){x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().push(']');})]
    ) >>
    ruleArg >>
    ruleBlockEnd[([](auto& ctx){
        assert(!x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().empty());
        x3::get<SBlockEndTag>(ctx).get().pop();
    })];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(ruleBlockEnd, ruleArg, ruleBlock3)
```

The code is on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99bc2adf54dd38c4).

**Question**: is this how we write recursive x3 parser for this kind of problem? With spirit Qi's locals and inherited attributes, the solution seems to be much simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `x3::with<>`.

However, I'd just write this:

```
auto const block_def =
    '{' >> *( block  | (char_ - '}')) >> '}'
  | '[' >> *( block  | (char_ - ']')) >> ']';
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c5307818962d721)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    rule<struct idBlock1> const block {"Block"};
    auto const block_def =
        '{' >> *( block  | (char_ - '}')) >> '}'
      | '[' >> *( block  | (char_ - ']')) >> ']';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(block)
}

int main() {
    std::string const input = R"({
    Some text.
    [
        {
            Some more text.
        }
        Some Text again.
        []
    ]
})";

    std::cout << "Parsed: " << std::boolalpha << parse(input.begin(), input.end(), Parser::block) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Parsed: true
```

### BUT - Code Duplication!

If you insist on generalizing:

```
auto dyna_block = [](auto open, auto close) {
    return open >> *(block | (char_ - close)) >> close;
};

auto const block_def =
    dyna_block('{', '}')
  | dyna_block('[', ']');
```

Comment: Added the preemptive response to the anti-code-duplication brigade :)