# How future-safe is it to write a parser with Boost Spirit X3?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3, future-proof

I'm considering writing what is essentially my first parser since forever (= since the compiler class at Uni which I've forgotten mostly).

Since I use C++, I was thinking of using Boost Spirit. Then I noticed there's the "regular" 2.5.2 and there's something magical subset of the code named Spirit X3.

I' also ve noticed that Boost Spirit X3 was announced/discussed/pre-released already 2 years ago, yet Boost Spirit's official version is 2.5.2. Finally, I read:

[Where is boost-spirit 3? Is it abandoned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799793/where-is-boost-spirit-3-is-it-abandoned)

So I "know" that it's not an abandoned project - but not a very actively maintained project. How "safe" is it for me to write a parser with Spirit X3? Is it possible it might fail / be dropped / be abandoned, or is it certain to become the main line of Boost Spirit release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already released, so there's little chance of it just vanishing.

> I liberally use X3 even in production code: After all, we do have tests for a reason.

That said, I know a number of hairy issues surround the linking of rules spread across separate translation units¹.

Here's a list of things that make me consider *not* using X3 in the following cases:

- where Qi's attribute transformation logic is more enticing (makes for more readable rules). See e.g.
- Phoenix integration is desired [Boost Spirit X3 cannot compile repeat directive with variable factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624149/boost-spirit-x3-cannot-compile-repeat-directive-with-variable-factor)
- Sharing rules across TUs is desired

Slightly less pressing differences are when:

- locals are involved ([*"X3 becomes a real tedium, (if not completely unbearable) with stateful rules (by which I mean rules with "locals")"*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=36214226#36214226)). A lot of it can be solved using `with<>`: [Boost Spirit X3 cannot compile repeat directive with variable factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624149/boost-spirit-x3-cannot-compile-repeat-directive-with-variable-factor) but I'm not convinced it's re-entrant
- lazy rule invocation is required²
- Lexer is desired (i.e. I wouldn't port a Qi/Lex grammar to X3, except by rewrite)

Note however, there are definite areas where X3 shines:

- compilation time
- ease of generating dynamic rules/custom directives (see [boost::spirit::x3 attribute compatibility rules, intuition or code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201023/boostspiritx3-attribute-compatibility-rules-intuition-or-code/37204957#37204957) or [Recursive x3 parser with results passing around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131508/recursive-x3-parser-with-results-passing-around/44132288#44132288))
- ease of creating custom parsers (e.g. [Spirit-Qi: How can I write a nonterminal parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669936/spirit-qi-how-can-i-write-a-nonterminal-parser/37823837#37823837))

---

¹ see the mailing list, and e.g. [x3 linker error with separate TU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791079/x3-linker-error-with-separate-tu) and [linking errors while separate parser using boost spirit x3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496357/linking-errors-while-separate-parser-using-boost-spirit-x3/40498579#40498579)

² In fact, it might be "easy" to create one by creating a custom parser, building on `with<>` and `any_parser<>`

Comment: So, I +1 you for the detailed answer, but - doesn't your answer imply that it's going to stay the "less-used brother" of the mainline into the future as well? Or are they just working on improving the stiuation with stateful rules, independent lexer etc.?

Comment: I merely confirm that it's officially experimental (unstable: the interface may change, there are warts). I have no claim about the future (I do not think it will remain less-used, that will probably depend on widespread adoption of c++14 only). They're working on the linking issues, but I'm not overly optimistic in that respect (TBF: I don't consider external linkage a requirement at all, but that's me). Lexer support is not gonna happen (me using [my crystal ball](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=20528855#20528855))

Comment: Despite the previous comment saying "Lexer support is not gonna happen", Peter Huene implemented his own lexer support in a personal project here: https://github.com/peterhuene/puppetcpp/blob/master/lib/include/puppet/compiler/lexer/lexer.hpp